# OpenCV - How to obtain the last position of white pixels in a video?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying to create a driving aid system using python and OpenCV. I used some binary threshold to get the lane lines white.

How can I get the last X value of the white pixels? I only found guides on detecting faces and lines.

Here is the [Video](https://gyazo.com/48b38ec4c790943d3c55b98b6e41fb8e)

Current code:

```
#Video Feed
ret, frame = cap.read()

#Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Comment: How do you want the last position? (a) in every frame? or  (b) at the end of the video stream?

Comment: In every frame (live) i want to use the last known X value of the white line

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nonzero()` function of `numpy` module. That gives you the induces of non-zero pixels, corresponding to the white pixels in your thresholded image. Then you can access the x coordinates using `whites[0]`. For example the value of the last white pixel in highest x and y coordinates is `thresh[whites[0][len(whites[0])-1]][whites[1][len(whites[1])-1]]`

```
import numpy
import cv2

#Video Feed
ret, frame = cap.read()

#Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get indices of all white pixels
whites = numpy.nonzero(thresh)

# print the last white pixel in x-axis, 
# which is obviously white
print thresh[whites[0][len(whites[0])-1]][whites[1][len(whites[1])-1]]
```

Comment: It works when i use it with the thresholding but  i now have a crop function before that: `leftframe = thresh[700:800, 250:550]` and when i try using it with leftframe `whites = np.nonzero(leftframe)` i get an error in the print line `IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: Can i define an area where the nonzero() will be looking?

Comment: You can definitely use it like that. For example, `nonzero(thresh[0:len(thresh[0]),0:len(thresh[1])])` gives the same result as `nonzero(thresh)`. The error you get occurs because you don't have any non-zero pixels in the area you have defined.

Comment: i put the print in a try/except and `whites = np.nonzero(thresh[800:810, 250:615])` but for some reason i keep getting the same value. I made a [GIF](https://i.gyazo.com/3e82424be1540e1b79d57d293ff7dcf2.mp4) from it.

Comment: What are you printing? Keep on mind that x gives rows and y gives cols. "The same value" (which is 9, I assume?) looks like the bottom border, i.e. max rows, because white pixels usually end up touching there in every frame. Try the other axis if that's not what you want.